# How to get only Highest Value with respect to Unique Value SQL PHP

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

I have a table

```
ID    Value     Version
1     TEST123     A
2     TEST123     B
3     DUMP123     A
4     DUMP123     B
5     DUMP123     C
```

i am looking to get values and display

```
2   TEST123    B
5   DUMP123    C
```

Output should be that it checks value gets all values only once and gets their highest version and displays it.

i am printing in PHP. Thank you for the response in advance. I could not find the solution anywhere.

Comment: I have removed the mysql tag since its misleading

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Value, MAX(Version) 
FROM yourTable 
GROUP BY Value
```

**[MySQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/210a6/1)**

**[SQL Server Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f18a9/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM   tempt t1
WHERE  (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   tempt t2
        WHERE  t1.val = t2.val
               AND t1.id < t2.id) = 0
```